# Form 2 sql gets fields from Form 1

Tags: php, html

I have two forms `form 1` and `form 2`.

The `form 1` has 20 fields of data and it's action is to update.
In `form 2` I have another action, but I want to get the 20 fields of data from `form 1`.

Is there any possible way to do this and how? Also form 1 and form 2 are in the same page.

I have already a solution which is putting 20 hidden fields in form 2 so form two can
get it from there which is tedious. But can I ask you guys is there a much easier idea?

Comment: Sorry, but the phrasing is a tad awkward here. You mention sql, but are you referring to fields as html form inputs, sql columns, sql records, what have yous? Oh, and what is your form 2 trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JaredDrake my bad edited. form 2 should perform two sql statements which the fields i can be taken from form one . bottom line is . . i want to get the data from the fields in form 1 so i can you them in my sql in my form 2. =)

Comment: teresko's future career in professional editing? I think so!

Comment: In the future, try to provide all relevant details initially (so people don't start writing answers that quickly become obsolete)

Answer (score 0):

You can save all the input from form 1 in a session variable and restore it in form 2. For that purpose, write a function which stores all $_GET and $_POST variables in an element of the $_SESSION array (using the parameter name as the key).

Comment: By the way Form 1 is in the same page as form 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution isn't bad, simple and Swift !
But the only better way, is ajax.
In ajax you are not limited to a form, you can get every fields from every forms and then send them manually.

**If you are not familier with ajax**, and you want to use your non-ajax solution, you can use one form and put all fields of two last forms in this new single form, and use one action file to response to this form.In server side you can check the value of a field which is unique.

client side :

```
<form action="test.php">

    <!-- fields of form 1 -->
    <input type="text" name="text1"/>
    <input type="text" name="text2"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="text" name="text20"/>

    <!-- fields of form 2 -->
    <input type="text" name="text21"/>
    <input type="text" name="text22"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="text" name="text40"/>

    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

server side:

```
<?php
      if ( isset($_GET["text1"]) )
          //do related jobs to form 1 here, and you can use all of filled fields
      else
          //do related jobs to form 2 here, and you can use all of filled fields
?>
```

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting i will research on that solution. Thank you.

Comment: in fact, we simulate two form in one form and in server side we make Decision

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is something that ever PHP developer has at some point solved.

The best way to do this would be to save data from previous form in `$_SESSION`. But this will be a valid solution, if you are filling out the form, while in the same session.

If you are building something like a e-commerce site, where user has to fill out several payment forms, or some large test-application, where students fill out multiform tests, it might be better to store data from each form in DB and associate it to `UserId`. This way the user gains ability to continue filling out the form from different location.

P.S. If you are using AJAX instead, you will mostly just add another layer of complexity on top of existing application. Especially if your skills in JavaScript are limited.

Comment: Oh ok like when I'm at form  one while submitting proceeding to form two i would $sql= select * from tb_blah where blahid=$_post. sorta like that?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @AntonApuaEscalante , if you submit the user data in two parts in database, then you will still have to associate the entry with user. Saving data from each form directly in table is only a valid solution if you are working with registered users. If there is no user-authentication associate with data from for, then you will still end up storing something in `$_SESSION`, only in this case it will not be all of the user data, but just the ID from last insert.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas will will try the $_SESSION method.

Comment: My bad i forgot to mention Form 1 is in the same page as form 2.

Comment: That completely changes your question.

Comment: The question is actually the same but i forgot to put the scenario that they are in 1 page. editing.